# Eclipse RCP menus and the new Natty Unity

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, rcp, natty

So I restarted my Eclipse RCP application after I upgraded my Ubuntu, and it seems that the Main menu has disappeared!

Does anyone know if this is the fault of the new Unity interface or something in SWT?

Comment: Apparently a bug has been filed at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Geniedesalpages mentions, it's the interaction between eclipse events and the Unity menu.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563

There should be updates to unity to allow eclipse to retain its old style menu bar.

PW

Answer (score 1):

If you're having the same problem as I had, about getting the Eclipse menu in the Unity Global Menu with HUD then this is what did the trick for me (nobody seems to be able to explain why it works, but for me and others it worked perfectly). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Indigo from their website.

(Change the commands accordingly if you're not using Vim for editing.)

1. Edit `libappmenu.so`:

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
   ```
2. Search for 'Eclipse':

   ```
   /Eclipse
   ```
3. Replace the 'E' with 'X':

   ```
   rX
   ```
4. This might be optional but doing it didn't hurt for me:

   ```
   $ sudo ldconfig
   ```

Now you should be good to go with Eclipse using the Unity Global Menu and The HUD working like a charm.

(Credit: [elvisd blog](http://elvisd.blogspot.com/2012/01/enable-eclipse-global-menu-integration.html))

Comment: Nope, now you have to edit your `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` (or another startup script you have) to start Eclipse like this:
`Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= path/to/eclipse`. But that is basically getting the Eclipse menu out of the HUD. Kind of a workaround until the menus work properly in the HUD.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can do

```
alias eclipse='UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0;eclipse'
```

But this will mean that you have to launch Eclipse from a terminal. If you want to launch Eclipse from Unity Dash then you have to add

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

as the first line in `/usr/bin/eclipse`.

This will show the file menu inside the application.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Was giving issue for 13.10 also.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file a bash script in the folder of Aptana/Eclipse and run the Aptana/Eclipse by this file.

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./AptanaStudio3
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Aptana Studio 3?